# Create CSV based on prefix in columns

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a CSV, but the rows have different number of columns, because in some rows, some values are missing. So there is no index. The "meaning" of each value is at the moment encoded by a prefix to the value. I need to clean my CSV so as to create a new one, that only holds values of certain columns, based on the prefix.

Looks like that:

```
001234;aA431;cFM33;jJE LE (3);xABCD;421;
004321;aB432;cPD99;433
006543;aC332;cHR31;x4231;499
```

The new CSV should have a header, its name can be the prefix (first letter) of the column:

```
0;a;c;4
01234;A431;FM33;21
04321;B432;PD99;33
06543;C332;HR31;99
```

I am starting to work with python pandas, so any hints in that direction would be esp. welcome.

Comment: what do you get when you do df=pd.read_csv(filename) and then print df.head(10)?

Comment: Is your original issue having unicode 'x1234;' characters in your file?

Comment: ```pythonpandas.errors.ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 28, saw 2
```

Comment: do `df=pd.read_csv(filename, sep = ';')` and then you can work on the df you get.

Comment: `sep = ';'` doesn't change the problem or error, because there are still different numbers of fields per row

Comment: Also the answer below doesn't get me over my first problem `Error tokenizing data. C Error:  Expected 14 fields in line 7, saw 15` My first row has 14 lines, this is not always the case.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
df1=df.astype(str).copy()
cols = df1.iloc[0].str[0].tolist()
df1=df1.apply(lambda x: x.str[1:])
df1.columns = cols
```

**input**

```
       A        B       C       D             E     F
0   1234    aA431   cFM33   jJE LE (3)  xABCD   421.0
1   4321    aB432   cPD99   433           NaN   NaN
2   6543    aC332   cHR31   x4231         499   NaN
```

**output**

```
print(df1)

      1        a      c     j             x     4
0   234     A431    FM33    JE LE (3)   ABCD    21.0
1   321     B432    PD99    33            an    an
2   543     C332    HR31    4231         99     an

print(df1)
```